# 3D shadow covering the scrollview on iphone

Tags: iphone, scrollview

I have attached an image that has a scrollview with page control and there is a border around the scroll view 
I wish to know how to achieve that I have already done the scroll view stuff.so just looking for a way to achieve that 3d shadow border

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just make a shadow in photoshop or whatever with transparency. Add this Image after you add the scrollview with addSubview to your view and it will look and feel like the scrollview in your attached picture.